# Using Meteor.disconnect() and Meteor.reconnect() to simulate reactivity

Tags: javascript, meteor, websocket, meteor-blaze, ddp

Which I know is terrible, but I don't know else to get reactivity on the server.
I'm using the publish-composite package as well:
https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite

I'm using Iron Router, where layout.html is the master template. In layout.js, I have:

```
Template.layout.created = function(){
    this.autorun(()=>{
        this.subscribe('currentUser')
        this.subscribe('friendsRecordsAnswers')
        this.subscribe('myRecordsGamesRounds')
        this.subscribe('queries')
    })
}
```

Here's an example of one of my publications:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('myRecordsGamesRounds', function(){
    if(this.userId){
        return {
            find(){
                return Records.find({userId: this.userId});
            },
            children:[{
                find(record){
                    return Games.find({_id: record.gameId})
                },
                children:[{
                    find(game){
                        return Rounds.find({gameId: game._id});
                    }
                }]
            },
            ]
        };
    }
})
```

This app is a game where you can invite other users. However, when a new user signs up, an existing user has to refresh the page before they can invite them to a game.
I currently have a setInterval at 2000ms running Meteor.disconnect() & Meteor.reconnect(), and that actually works ok so far. But I'm sure there is a better way.
Thanks!

Comment: Are other users published as _children_ of a `publishComposite`? I've seen problems with this where the children are not reactive but the parent is.

Comment: I've realized that the issue that I'm making an HTTP.call() within another publication, and apparently this doesn't automatically work in a reactive manner. Sadly don't have a solid yet though :(

Answer (score 0):

In the github example with 2 levels of children, you can see that the second level children reference the 2 levels of parents: `comment` and `post` in that order:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('topTenPosts', {
    find: function() {
        // Find top ten highest scoring posts
        return Posts.find({}, { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 10 });
    },
    children: [
        {
            find: function(post) {
                // Find post author. Even though we only want to return
                // one record here, we use "find" instead of "findOne"
                // since this function should return a cursor.
                return Meteor.users.find(
                    { _id: post.authorId },
                    { limit: 1, fields: { profile: 1 } });
            }
        },
        {
            find: function(post) {
                // Find top two comments on post
                return Comments.find(
                    { postId: post._id },
                    { sort: { score: -1 }, limit: 2 });
            },
            children: [
                {
                    find: function(comment, post) {
                        // Find user that authored comment.
                        return Meteor.users.find(
                            { _id: comment.authorId },
                            { limit: 1, fields: { profile: 1 } });
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

You're not doing that in your code, and you're essentially only passing the 1st level children reference, but not the root. So I think you just need to do:

```
Meteor.publishComposite('myRecordsGamesRounds', function(){
    if(this.userId){
        return {
            find(){
                return Records.find({userId: this.userId});
            },
            children:[{
                find(record){
                    return Games.find({_id: record.gameId})
                },
                children:[{
                    find(game, record){
                        return Rounds.find({gameId: game._id});
                    }
                }]
            },
            ]
        };
    }
})
```

I would think that because you're passing the root to the bottom children, it would be looking back at it.

I may be wrong here... I have used this package but gave up on it a while back because as soon as you want to do search, you end up with a huge mess.

I prefer using https://github.com/peerlibrary/meteor-reactive-publish  which is much cleaner and lets you do what you want in code as opposed to nesting objects.

Comment: I've tried the meteor-reactive-publish library, but found that it massively slowed down the application. A further issue I've realized is that one of my other publications contains an HTTP.call() method, and am unsure how to make that respond reactively.